# Blender not Opening On Mac

Tags: installation, osx

I downloaded Blender for the first time, but it stops unexpectedly every single time. I have tried several Blender versions, but I keep getting the same problem. I have no idea what's going wrong. I did a restart and the Unarchiver is up to date. And I can't find a Blender folder in the Application Support.

My Mac was running on OS 10.11.6. Updated to 10.12. but it makes no difference.

When I open blender from the terminal I get this:

```
Writing: blender.crash.txt
Segmentation fault: 11
```

And the blender.crash.txt files says:

```
# backtrace
0   blender                             0x0000000100baa46a BLI_system_backtrace + 58
1   blender                             0x00000001001549fa blender_crash_handler + 362
2   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00007fff9854452a _sigtramp + 26
3   ???                                 0x0000000109161330 0x0 + 4447408944
4   blender                             0x000000010019b6f8 fsmenu_read_system + 328
5   blender                             0x000000010019d5e4 ED_file_read_bookmarks + 68
6   blender                             0x000000010019d579 ED_file_init + 9
7   blender                             0x000000010016623f WM_init + 175
8   blender                             0x0000000100154751 main + 3521
9   blender                             0x000000010015397c start + 52
10  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
```

Comment: To give us some more information to work with, launch Blender from the Terminal. Open the Terminal app and then type in `/Applications/blender.app/Contents/MacOS/blender`. This assumes that you just dragged Blender into the Applications folder. If you did something else, replace the `/Applications/` part of the code accordingly. Post the output to the Terminal window as an edit to your answer so we can help better.

Comment: It sounds like a bug. I use Blender on a Mac but have never encountered the problem you describe. Currently I'm on macOS 10.12.4 running Blender 2.78c. So it may be a problem only affecting certain versions, combinations of versions, or even hardware configurations. The best thing you can do is [file a bug report](http://archive.blender.org/development/report-a-bug/) providing as much system config info as possible. Other than that, maybe a clean installation of macOS and Blender could solve it.

Comment: Another thing to try is removing the contents of ~/Library/Application Support/Blender in case an add-on or something is causing a conflict.

Comment: Solved it by downloading 2.78f  >>  https://builder.blender.org/download/